# How can I put a fixed logo in the nav bar at the top?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how I can put an image next to the nav bar. I tried many different ways but I cannot solve it, because if I want to redirect the logo to the index page then the navbar doesn't work, and vice versa. In my website I am doing some tests, so as you can see in the link attached, the logo image at the top and the navbar doesn't redirect you to the index page, even though i"ve added the "href" code. This is my website and the page I want to display the logo: [massaviu.cat/contacte.html](http://www.massaviu.cat/contacte.html)

You can actually press Ctrl+U to see the coding. Thank you <3

The code here:

```
<div class="logo-massaviu">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" width="20%"></a>
</div>
<div>   
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a class="link" href="#">concerts</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="discografia.html">discografia</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="galeria.html">galeria</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="#">botiga</a></li>

        <li><a class="link" href="contacte.html">contacte</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS style sheet for the logo and the nav:

```
.nav{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b8d2db;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;

}

.logo-massaviu {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Edited with the code. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your navigation is overlapping your logo making it so you can't click it.
Use `z-index` to move the logo on top of the navigation. Then change the width of the outer div to a set value so it doesn't overlap the navigation.

```
.logo-massaviu {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 198px;
}
```

```
<div class="logo-massaviu">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" width="100%"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct. Keep in mind you can use any integer value for the `z-index` so long as the element you want top has a greater value than the other.

Comment: @NamKim That's why I use 2147483648 __/s__

Comment: @Laif Okay... fine any number less than or equal to 2147483647

Comment: @abney317 Not working at all. Now I cannot click on the nav bar :(

Comment: Updated. Set the logo div width and change the image width to 100%

Answer (score 0):

As nav is overlapping on logo div, try giving it some width. try the below CSS for .nav

```
.nav{
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Not working either. Now I can click the logo to return to the Index page, but I cannot click the nav bar :(